# How to properly use renderTo property in extjs?

Tags: image, dom, extjs

I am trying to render the image over existing image or over existing panel, but I am getting an error.
According to documentation `renderTo:` could be followed by *the id of the element, a DOM element or an existing Element that this component will be rendered into.*

However, I am always getting error. Here is my code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('MyPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            title: 'My Panel',
            width: 690,
            height: 410,
            itemId: 'pp2',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'image',
                itemId: 'pp',
                id: 'pp1',
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                src: 'https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg',
            }]
        });

        var p = Ext.create('MyPanel');

        var crop = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
            height: 165,
            width: 220,
            src: 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            //renderTo: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('MyPanel[itemId=pp]').getEl().dom
            //renderTo: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('MyPanel').getEl().dom
            //renderTo: 'pp2'
        });
    }
});
```

So, with `renderTo: Ext.getBody(),` it works, but if i want to render the image over the panel, when I try to specify `dom` it fails.

Within the same question, another issue popped up into my mind. How to specify a function as a parameter of specific method? For example, in previous case, the following block is also incorrect:

```
renderTo: function(){
    return Ext.getBody()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid access HTML from ExtJs. The framework hides it from developers.
The panel is not rendered at the moment when you are initialising the your panel, you must put appropriate logic in the afterrender event handler:

```
Ext.define('MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    width: 400,
    height: 200,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'image',
        itemId: 'pp',
        id: 'pp1',
        height: 250,
        width: 350,
        src: 'https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg',
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (panel) {
            var crop = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
                height: 165,
                width: 220,
                floating: true,
                src: 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg',
                //renderTo: panel.getEl().dom // <-- Bad practice, but works
            });
            // Good practice. 
            panel.add(crop);
            crop.show();
        }
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        this.title = this.getTheTitle();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    getTheTitle: function () {
        return "My wonderful Panel";
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('MyPanel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        });
    }
});
```

To set a property of the class you can use initComponent method (something like constructor of the class).

Comment: Thank you. But, this works only for panel, and not for image. I tried both (bad & good practice) for image (```itemId: 'pp',```) but it raised an error. I also tried to put this in ```load``` event of image, but without success. Can you tell me how to render this crop component into ```itemId: 'pp',``` and not into panel itself? Your explanation for the second  part concerning properties was very clear and useful - thank you.

Comment: @zuriosam html img tag does not support subcomponents.

Comment: As for the second part, it is clear when the ```title``` or some similar direct property is concerned. But, how can I  return function value for example for ```image height``` in the previous example. In this case it is not possible to construct path to property like ```this.<image height>```.

Comment: You can override, extend.. Ext.Img class and add appropriate custom methods.